# Microsoft graph API: Unable to fetch users with the generated access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have registered the application in Azure portal and i have generated the client_secret.
I require the client grant flow and i have given application permissions also. I have granted the admin consent also as I am the admin myself.

I am able to generate the access token with the given url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/47be0abf-c6a1-4f04-a665-dceb081c4ff1/oauth2/v2.0/token?client_id=********&client_secret=******&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=User.ReadBasic.All%20User.Read%20User.ReadWrite%20User.Read.All%20User.ReadWrite.All%20Directory.Read.All%20Directory.ReadWrite.All%20Directory.AccessAsUser.All
```

However, when i use the token generated to access the following url, I get the insufficient privileges message.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Authorization Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFEQ29NcGpKWHJ4VHE5Vkc5dGUtN0ZYNndkRlV3aTBKbGlHcWhEWkgybFRlYWh6SUhUX0VsazFaYTFuUHRzNWo3SW5xMDBmbnNNRkpNUWRYdWdVZnpaZ0cxT19uenNPTXpwN2tpUFFIR2VHTnlBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoiQ3RmUUM4TGUtOE5zQzdvQzJ6UWtacGNyZk9jIiwia2lkIjoiQ3RmUUM4TGUtOE5zQzdvQzJ6UWtacGNyZk9jIn0.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.fXEs7eClm5SYXychcKXbTfcc5gtvyyMa5fDWuGu2vqQ4Zc6V0jJSHSeksRiOzYE8SOJXRTmI9vJtbs2XIMFr0CRHeTgoCDReV8JWJ8yhOKiDnc-_2AHtSoBnqt6ibF0eX4AzkyioJd24-uYTSkheC_zDpd6GS3T5T077BU_1M7kpngXDfEICi38VkddcpdBUG8FgHUSPq0S9fCosIB4_JPwspq3QC6jJyoRrj1Yj2oR8FwBA1dpgWq_e0QoGnWXgT6EhBKedjY0hwHGY-F73ndvRlAKKW63JYucdOtRyC2zFDc4DPwhN1nyPlh86_Y0Zru8UTb0QgWRFKbGZwQcEOg
```

I have tried changing the permission and added and removed the permissions.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "aa38f822-7325-44ad-9127-3cb4779578bf",
        "date": "2019-06-11T11:42:16"
    }
}
```

}

**Updated :** Included the permission screenshot configuration

[image: permission and consent]

JWT Debugger output for tokens:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/f77804fb-8607-4e96-9fae-231360cc82b7/",
  "iat": 1560273380,
  "nbf": 1560273380,
  "exp": 1560277280,
  "aio": "42ZgYKjulnV3u/vJZNN0gz3ld2ZpAwA=",
  "app_displayname": "clmapp",
  "appid": "82ad79f2-27c7-4304-92f6-e3ffdb637e72",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/f77804fb-8607-4e96-9fae-231360cc82b7/",
  "tid": "f77804fb-8607-4e96-9fae-231360cc82b7",
  "uti": "BpTbRLEb5ECSO3qjslIgAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_tcdt": 1376441181
}
```

Comment: Is the problem still remain? Or resolved?

Comment: It is still there. I tried the solution given below but it didn't work. You advice would be welcome.

Comment: Please take a look. I hope your problem would resolved! Let me know if any problem remains.

Comment: Is it alright now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try following way:

**Permission:**

Make sure you have following [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#permissions):

[image]

**Grant permission On Azure Portal:**

**Step:1**

Select `Application Permission` On `API permissions` menu

[image]

**Step:2**

Select `User.ReadWrite.All` under `Application Permission` part But `User.Read.All` also alright.

[image]

**Token Request Format:**

**URL:**`https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token`

> **For V2.0 URL:**`https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token`

`HTTP Verb: POST`

```
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:b603c7be-a866-4-e6921e61f925
client_secret:Vxf1SluKbguf3wE5oGl/2XDSeZ8wL/Yp8ns4sc=
resource:https://graph.microsoft.com
```

> For V2.0 scope Will be : `scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Decode Token & Confirm permission:**

You can use [`https://jwt.io/`](https://jwt.io/) to decode your token to make sure you have required permission: See the below screen shot:

[image]

**Request For User List:**

With your `Token` Request on this endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`. See the screen shot below. I have successfully get all the user list.

[image]

Comment: I would only require to give the application permission for client grant flow- as per the docs ?

Comment: Yeah application permission is alright. Just follow my sample. If you still any issue let me know.

Comment: the token i generate does not show the roles when i verify in jwt debugger? is that alright?

I tried with the same steps. Still the same error.

Comment: No its not alright , I guess your permission is not granted, first `API permissions> add permisssion > Microsoft Graph > Application permissions > User > User.Read.All > Add Permissions > Grand Admin Concent For > Yes`. Then wait 30 second then generate your token and request for user List

Comment: Token should show on JWT when you would decode. Then Try. Let me know if everything alright.

Comment: The status is still the same. I updated the permissions and granted the admin consent. After that waited few minutes. But i still do not see roles in the jwt debugger the generated token.

Comment: Make sure your given permission tenant and token tenant is same, some where you are doing wrong. Would suggest to follow my solution step by step.

Comment: Fellow all of my screen shot it's details.

Comment: I am using a tenant-id. I tried the `YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com`. where i guess yourTenant means the registered app name.

I got the below error  

` "AADSTS90002: Tenant 'clmapp.onmicrosoft.com' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant.`.

I have verified again tenant id. both are same

Comment: Tenant name/Id is different from application name/id. Why didnt you points that you do not have active subscription. While post questions its better to describe all of your scenario.

Comment: I am sorry about the earlier comment. I was able to generate the token using the myapp.onmicrosoft.com. I tried with tenant id also now. It is working. I got the output.

Thanks for the support. You have been great help

Comment: Tenant name and Id both valid

Comment: Glad to hear, thanks. By the way what did you miss?

Answer (score 0):

When using the OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant flow, your scope value should use the built-in `.default` scope for the resource your are trying to access. This is mentioned in the reference article: [Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret)

In your case, the resource you are trying to access is Microsoft Graph, so your `scope` value in the token request should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id-or-domain}/oauth2/v2.0/token
    &grant_type=client_credentials
    &client_id={client-id}
    &client_secret={client-secret}
    &scope=https%3a%2f%2fgraph.microsoft.com%2f.default
```

Note that for this to succeed, the app's required permissions must be configured (Azure portal > Azure Active Directory > App registrations > API permissions) *and granted*:

[image: Choose and grant required application permissions]

Comment: I tried with default scope again. In fact, I had tried it earlier also. It shows the similar error message. I also have updated the question with screenshot of permissions

Comment: As per link you have shared. I changed the `accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2`. But it also did not resolve anything.

Comment: Are you sure the app from your screenshot (with the granted permissions) is the same app as the one you're using to obtain the access token (client_id)? Are you sure that the tenant in which you've granted the permissions is the same tenant you're using for your token request?

Comment: yes. Pretty sure about it. In fact registered a new app. But it did not work.

Comment: The token request in your question uses tenant ID `47be0abf-c6a1-4f04-a665-dceb081c4ff1`, but the token example you show came from tenant ID `f77804fb-8607-4e96-9fae-231360cc82b7`. Can you please update the question so that the token request and API request (and error response) matches the actual tenant and token you used? Do _not_ include the full access token like you've done above, as anyone could have used that to access your organization's data. It _is_ OK to include the decoded token (the JSON) because that can't be used against the API.