# Error 403 on access to AD User from Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps, azureportal

I want to manage my AD Users with an Azure Logic App and i have some trouble when i try to "get user" using the connector "get user" of Azure Active Directory.

```
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorInsufficientPermissionsInAccessToken",
    "message": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ProfileAccessDeniedException' was thrown.",
```

To "get user", i create a specific AD User (a Guest) with Global administrator role (so the user can create/update AD Users).  After i put the Active Directory Connector "get user" and sign in with this user.

Did i miss something ?

Comment: Hello @MdFaridUddinKiron, i don't use Graph API (maybe i will) but Active directory connector on a Logic App (like [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oA6Vq6__mT8)) and i give "all" permissions to my user

Comment: I have also an Active Directory Account and my user has full access for create/update/read Users on AD

Comment: When you put an Azure AD Connector "get user", the component ask you to sign in and ask you to allow it to have full access on AD Users (just have to Accept) and it creates a link between your Logic App and your AD (you can see it on API Connection on your logic app).

Comment: Hello @MdFaridUddinKiron, i will do the test today but not now, i will tell you if your answer works.

Comment: Okay looking forward to hear from you. Feel free to share if you have any more concern. Thanks

Comment: So i put my Azure AD connector on my logic app, change the connection to sign in with my tenant (wich is admin) and i have the same thing (Forbidden). Do i need to create a new tenant user ? Different from the admin ?

Comment: Yeah, any tenant user can be workable, Just add as `New user` not guest user. For example `exampleUser@tenant.onmicrosoft.com`. Let know if any more issue you encounter.

Comment: Ok now it works but i can only get my new tenant user, if i search an other user i have this message : _"Resource 'blabla@xxxxx.com' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."_

Comment: I have noticed that, currently only sign in user can get his own information. List or other user is not accessible. But its developing frequently. Hope you would get that feature soon. Create user works fine. Thanks.

Comment: it's working when you give the Object ID and not the UserName, strange... But thanks for your help !

Comment: Other user? I haven't try with object Id. Glad to hear it working.

Comment: Yes it works with other users but only with Object ID

Comment: I also noticed guest user also working with objejct Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason Of Your Error:**

You are trying with personal account with guest privilege in that case need to set `Object ID`. I have tested and reproduce it. See the below screen shot:

[image]

**Resolution Of Error:**

Switch your connection like below:

[image]

**User Tenant User Email:**

You could try following way with tenant user credentials Like `exampleUser@tenant.onmicrosoft.com` instead of `example@outlook.com` or `example@domain.com` :

[image]

**Point To Remember:**

1. Guest user has no privilege to perform this operation but with `Object ID` it can be done.
2. User must be tenant specific user for example
   `exampleUser@tenant.onmicrosoft.com`

For more details you could take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543107/microsoft-graph-api-unable-to-fetch-users-with-the-generated-access-token/56546862#56546862)