# Microsoft OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials - Unable to retrieve permission to scope even with Granted Admin Consent on Azure

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on daemon service that retrieves the list of contacts from Microsoft Graph, that does not prompt Microsoft Authentication to the user. However, I'm not able to retrieve the permissions I set in Microsoft Azure even with granted admin consent.

I use Postman to generate a token with the following information.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/0835055b-8a00-4130-b07a-037430dd000d/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

The following json is the result I get

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "profile openid email https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "ext_expires_in": 3600,
    "access_token": "{MY_TOKEN_HERE}"
}
```

Token is generated successfully but the token returned does not include the permission with granted admin consent I set in MS Azure at portal.azure.com > Registered App > API Permission.

I have Microsoft Graph - Users.Read and Contacts Read with green ticks on admin consent required. See image below:

[Microsoft Azure - API Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7y58.png)

And without the scope, I'm not able to retrieve the list of contacts with given token.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "63a24a22-34f7-42a1-a9d5-d7aaf598f4d6",
            "date": "2019-07-01T02:59:15"
        }
    }

}
```

Is there anything I missed? I assumed when the admin has granted consents, I should be able to include the API in scopes to generate tokens.

I saw there is a similar issue here but there is no solutions that work for me: 
[Microsoft graph API: Unable to fetch users with the generated access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543107/microsoft-graph-api-unable-to-fetch-users-with-the-generated-access-token)

Comment: What API are you calling? I can see that you added `User.Read` in `delegated permissions`, which is cannot be obtained in access_token via `client_credentials` flow. You need to add `Application permissions` for client_credentials flow.

Comment: You can also use `https://jwt.ms` to decode your access token with debugging purpose to check if it contains enough permissions. For user delegated permissions, it's in `scp` claim, For application permission, it's in `roles`claim. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims

Comment: @Wayne, Thanks for replying! I'm trying to call "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts" but it returns AccessDenied. I also tried to use jwt but I don't see the scope "Contacts.Read" in it

Comment: I have Graph -> Contacts.Read under Application Permissions, but it didn't show up in my scopes. I don't have [roles] claim either..

Comment: Thanks for your information. May I know have you consented that permissions already? If not, please use an global admin account to click Grant admin consent button in your app registration.

Comment: @Wayne, yes my global administrator has already clicked "Grant Admin Consent" but it still did not work :/ You can see it from the picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7y58.png

Comment: @Wayne, Hmmm.. does it only work when a Global Administrator grant the permission? Not sure why but it works now

Comment: Yes, it can only work with a Global admin account.

Comment: If this issue has been resolved, please paste the answer below. This will be beneficial to others.

Comment: Sorry I'm still investigating as it still does not work most of the time. Will update soon.

Comment: May I know if your problem was solved?

Comment: Not really.. can't get why when it comes to application permission it never works for me. It only works when I use delegated permissions instead and granted admin consent.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot, the contacts.read you granted is an application permission. And, you have only one delegated permission: user.read .

However, if you want to call the graph api : graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts , you need to use delegated permission. It will represent the user. So you can get the information for "me".  And based on [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) , you need to grant the Contacts.Read (Contacts.ReadWrite for writing) delegated permission.

[image]

If you want to use application permission, then you need to get access token with [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token). Token got in this way can be used for application permission. And you should call the api as following : graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/contacts